# SQL Replace value in table after 90 days

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So to make my project GDPR friendly, I have to remove all customer data after 90 days.

This is how the `sales` table looks like (the input is just for example), using phpMyAdmin:

```
| ID | CUSTOMER  | EMAIL               | PRODUCT | DATE                | 
|  1 | Ken James | ken.jam@example.com | 4816419 | 2019-12-25 10:26:19 |
|  2 | Amy Wen   | amywen@example.com  | 6662341 | 2019-11-23 10:26:19 |
|  3 | Chris Pet | chripet@example.com | 4816419 | 2019-05-05 10:26:19 |
```

Is there somehow I can automatically replace the `CUSTOMER` and `EMAIL` with just `XXXXXX` if the `DATE` is older then 90 days?

Comment: Yes. Run a scheduled job of some sort to query the database, check for dates older than 90 days and change the other fields. Some database engines have this ability built in (e.g. SQL Agent jobs in MS SQL Server), in other cases you may have to run it via a Scheduled Task / cron job in the operating system

Comment: P.S. I'm not a GDPR expert by any means, and I'm not a lawyer, but AFAIK there is no specific requirement to delete data after 90 days. How have you come to need that requirement? The GDPR requires that you specify how long you will retain a user’s information, it doesn't mandate a specific timetable. Have you imposed that time limit on yourself?

Comment: You should store e-mail in the customers table, not in the sales table.

Comment: Removing all customer data after 90 days may be 'GDPR friendly', but it is not a requirement under GDPR.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built on Scheduler.

But it has to be [Enabled](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-configuration.html)

```
CREATE EVENT event1
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' DAY
STARTS '2020-08-17 00:00:01' -- should be in the future
DO
    UPDATE sales  
        SET EMAIL = 'xxxxxxxx', CUSTOMER = 'xxxxxxxx' 
    WHERE EMAIL <> 'xxxxxxxx' AND  CUSTOMER <> 'xxxxxxxx' AND `DATE` < DATE_ADD(NOW(),  INTERVAL -90 DAY);
```

Comment: This way you're moving your app and its logic to the database. Worst scenario ever.

Comment: to run querys periodically you have to use a schelduler and it doesn't matter where you run iot from shell app or mysql server

Comment: But you should keep the logic inside the code of your app, not inside some magical event inside the db. I would get fired and laughed at at my work if I would propose such a solution.

Comment: a app is not 24/7 open , that why a 90 day periodically removing , can't be run in the app, it must be run on the server. such maintenance queries are always doen o9n the server.and the code works regardless where it runs

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

```
UPDATE *table_name*
SET CUSTUMER = 'xxxxxxx', EMAIL = 'xxxxxxx'
WHERE CURRENT_DATE() - DATE > 90;
```

CURRENT_DATE() return the date of the current date
(You can also use GETDATE() instead of CURRENT_DATE())

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps too long for a comment.

90 days seems a bit aggressive based on what I know about GDPR.

That said, what you are doing is quite dangerous, at least from an analytic and financial perspective.  Knowing that a customer has made multiple purchases over time can be quite important.  And GDPR is pretty explicit that you can keep historical information about active (and recently former) customers.  (Of course, I'm not a lawyer and even if I were, you should be very suspicious about free advie over the web.)

That said, your `sales` table should be *designed* to be privacy compliant.  How?  Store the customer information in a different table.

So, the `sales` table should look like:

```
| ID | CUSTOMERID | PRODUCT | DATE                | 
|  1 |     1      | 4816419 | 2019-12-25 10:26:19 |
|  2 |     2      | 6662341 | 2019-11-23 10:26:19 |
|  3 |     3      | 4816419 | 2019-05-05 10:26:19 |
```

This table is perfectly fine from a privacy perspective, assuming that the `CUSTOMERID` is strictly used internally.

You should then have a `CUSTOMERS` table:

```
| CUSTOMERID | CUSTOMER  | EMAIL               | LASTSALEDATE                | 
|      1     | Ken James | ken.jam@example.com | 2019-12-25 10:26:19 |
|      2     | Amy Wen   | amywen@example.com  | 2019-11-23 10:26:19 |
|      3     | Chris Pet | chripet@example.com | 2019-05-05 10:26:19 |
```

This is the table where you can replace the name, address, email, phone number, and so on with `NULL` values (or `'XXXX'` if you prefer).

This structure allows you to maintain the internal history of repeated purchases and purchase dates and so on -- even when the data has been anonymized.  By putting all the PII in one place, it is easier to maintain, audit, and ensure that it meets the requirements of GDPR and other privacy laws.